# How to edit user activation mail body in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x, extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 user registration form .After successful registration user will get Activation link throw their registered mail id . I want to Add some content to email body(Footer). i have tried a lot but not succeeded.

Code : registration.php

i tried this .

```
$emailBody = JText::sprintf(
                'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY_NOPW',
                $data['name'],
                $data['sitename'],
                $data['siteurl'].'index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.activate&token='.$data['activation'],
                $data['siteurl'],
                $data['username'].'regarts: mysitename'

            );
```

but the problem is "user name" and 'regarts: mysitename' both are coming in a same line. even 
 all so not working . what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are editing core files. When an updates comes all your changes lost!.

do not edit core files you can override default messages by adding template overrides.

go to admin -> Extension -> Language Manager -> Override ->

Add your constant set your custom message. 
Done !

Hope it make sense..